# Using 2 Instance of GoogleMap API V2 Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using 2 instance of Google Map in my application in 2 different tab.
All the activity in respective Tab is managed by TabGroupActivity.

When i am in the first tab and on top is my Map Activity , i am able to add markers using asynctask.

But the problem arises when i go to other tab with the previous tab'S Map Activity on TOP , the current tab's Map activity calls webservices to get Map data but not able to update the markers and i am seeing all the markers which i added on the other tab's activity.

Can anyone please suggest some work around for this ? It would be a great help.

Edit : Code

onCreate(){

```
    if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (mMapCard == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            // mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            // R.id.mapFragement)).getMap();
            mapFragement = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragement));
            System.out.println("mMapCard object" + mapFragement.getId());
            mMapCard = mapFragement.getMap();

            // mMapCard = ((SupportMapFragment)
            // getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragement)).getMap();

        }
    } else {

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this,
                requestCode);
        dialog.show();
    }
```

}
setUpMapForCurrentLocation();
        fetchCardMapItems();   // This method adds Card. Here i am adding Markers to Map and storing all the Marker Object in List for removing marker on Pause

@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

```
    if (MarkerListHashMap != null && MarkerListHashMap.size() > 0) {

        Toast.makeText(CardMapActivity.this, MarkerListHashMap.size() + "",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        for (int i = 0; i < MarkerListHashMap.size(); i++) {
            MarkerListHashMap.get(i).remove();

        }
    }
    mMapCard.clear();
    System.gc();

}
```

.........................................................

The same code is there in other Map Activity - in other code with some different Instances.

Thanks in Advance.
Rakesh

Comment: show your relevant code.

Comment: @EmilAdz I have edited the question and added Code.can you please share how can i resolve this issue... This is like a show stopper issue in my app..